# I want the values from database on a combo box after matching some criteria

Tags: php, combobox

Here is my html code:

```
<form action="ProductProcess.php" method="post">
    <h1> Update</h1>
        <label>Product Type: </label>
        <select name="protype">
            <option> Hair Treatment </option>
            <option> Hair Styling</option> 
        </select>  <br> <br>

        <label>Product Name</label> 
        <select name="proname">
            <option>
             //Here i want the values 
           </option>
        </select><br> <br>
      </form>
```

Here is the working php code:

```
<?php
  $protype=$_POST['protype'];
  //Connect
  $query=mysql_query("Select Product_Name from tbl_Products where Product_Type='".$protype."'");            
            if(!$numrows=mysql_num_rows($query)==0)
            {
                while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
                {
                    echo $row['Product_Name'];
                }
            }
?>
```

The php code displays the value on the other page. I want the results on the combo box of the above HTML page.

Comment: [How do I ask a **good** question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to place the working code inside the `<select>` tag.

```
<select name="proname">
    <option>
     <?php
      $protype=$_POST['protype'];
      //Connect
      $query=mysql_query("Select Product_Name from tbl_Products where Product_Type='".$protype."'");            
        if(!$numrows=mysql_num_rows($query)==0)
        {
            while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
            { ?>
                <option value="<? echo $row['Product_Name']; ?>">
                <? echo $row['Product_Name']; ?>
                </option>
          <? }
        }
      ?>
</select>
```